# Terminology of excel/spreadsheet grid

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am looking for some information as to what is the correct terminology for the following four sections in an excel or Google sheets document:

[image]

My thoughts were:

1. Value cell
2. Header cell
3. Column letters
4. Row numbers

Is there some standardized terminology here? Note that 1 & 2 must have separate terminology as they describe two different things in my use case.

Comment: 1. Have you deliverily used `excel` instead of `spreadsheet` on the title? 2. Have you already read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet? 3. Have you hear about OASIS and ODF?

Comment: 1=headers and 2=data

Comment: @TimWilliams I assume you mean 2 is headers and 1 is data. What would 3 and 4 be then?

Comment: Please briefly describe your use case. Is this layout a "simple table" and "Excel Table" or how do you call it?

Comment: @David542 - yes my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your image:

1: **Cells** (which contain **data** or **values**)
2: **Data Headings** or **Titles** (which are still **values** within **cells**)
3: **Column Headings** (with column letters)
4: **Row Headings** (with row numbers)

---

[image: image: parts of a worksheet]

---

[image: image: cells vs tables]

- `A1` refer is a cell (which currently has a value of "`ID`".)
- `A1:C5` is a **range of cells** containing my **data**.
  (a rectangle where `A1` = top left, and `C5` = bottom right)
- Range `A1:C1` contains my **headings**.
- Range `A2:C5` contains my **values**.
- I copied `A1:C5` to `E1:G5`, and then I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
  The range `E1:G5` is now a [***Table***](https://support.office.com/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c).

* <sub>Note that in this image I [hid the **gridlines**](https://support.office.com/article/show-or-hide-gridlines-on-a-worksheet-3ef5aacb-4539-4ad5-9945-5ed53772dc4d) and I added my own ***borders*** for range `A1:C5`.</sub>

---

[image: image: formula breakdown]

---

## More Terminology: <sub><sup>(that you didn't ask for)</sup></sub>

While we're discussing semantics, I'll clarify a couple grammatical pet-peeves:

- We do not work with *"an Excel"* or *"a PowerPoint"* or *"a Word"*.  We work with;

  - an ***Excel Workbook*** (or perhaps only a single Excel ***worksheet***), *or,*
  - a ***PowerPoint Presentation*** (or perhaps only a single PowerPoint ***slide***), *or,*
  - a ***Word Document***.
- The word *"**Data**"* is always *singular*<sup>***†***</sup>.  You never have *"datas"*.  [image: image: 'No Datas' Sign]
  <sup><sup>([Exception](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/A_Fistful_of_Datas_(episode)))</sup></sup>
- In Excel, a *"**Macro**"* is something you *record* with the [[image]**Macro Recorder**](https://support.office.com/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b).

  A macro generates *"**VBA Code**"*.

  If you modify the macro, or write VBA, you are working with "***Code***" -- not "writing a macro". 
  <sup>(See: *"[Recording a **Macro** to Generate **Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code)"* and [**Revising Recorded VBA Macros**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros))</sup>
- In programming terms, the word "***Code***" is always *singular*.  You never have *"codes"*.
- [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) is an acronym **V**isual **B**asic for **A**pplications.
- [**Visual Basic** (VB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic), [**VB.NET**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), and [**VBScript** (VBS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) are similar but not interchangeable so it's important to be specific when Googling or discussing your code.

Since a tiny programming mistake can have big consequences, clarity in capitalization, spacing, indentation and general neatness **matter** when we're talking about programming!

<sup>***†***</sup> <sub>Depending on who you ask, others will have different opinions about the technical terms or grammatically correct words, but I think these are generally accepted.  Most people will usually know what you're talking about if you stick to these terms.</sub>

---

> ## The *Official* Documentation <sub><sup>(plus examples, tips, training, etc...)</sup></sub>
>
> - **For Excel:** [https://**support.office.com**/excel](https://support.office.com/excel)
>     ...or ask [specific](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) Excel questions at [**SuperUser**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel).
> - **For VBA:** [https://**msdn.microsoft.com**/vba](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba)
>     ...or ask [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) programming questions on [**Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba).

Comment: oh this is fantastic. Thanks for putting in the time for this, it's super helpful and I hope others will find this helpful as well. Cheers.

Comment: Also: would one ever refer to the first row as the "Fields" and the rest of the cells as "Values"? Or that's not really too common?

Comment: re: *"Fields"* - short answer: **No, not that's not a correct term**.  ...but that's where some of the terminology gets mixed up with Microsoft Access - which is easy to do because the two applications are similar in many ways, and a projects will often involve both.  A **"row"** in an Excel worksheet is like a **"record"** in an Access table, and a **"column"** in an Excel worksheet is like a ***"field"*** in an Access table.  The *title* of the Access field would be called a ***field name*** (whereas "field" refers to the name and all of the data "underneath" it.)  Clear as mud? ‎

Comment: Here's a link to **[Microsoft Access Database Basics](https://support.office.com/article/database-basics-a849ac16-07c7-4a31-9948-3c8c94a7c204)** including terminology.

Comment: One more thing - As a developer I'm a huge fan of many of Google's products but for office docs, I stick to the standard, Office. Most day-to-day functionality is interchangeable but there are exceptions. I realize the no-cost aspect of Google Sheets is nice, but many don't realize that as a [developer](//developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office) or a current/recent [student](//www.microsoft.com/en-ca/education/products/office/default.aspx), ***you can get Office 365 for FREE*** along with other goodies from training to a free logo? (...not a trial; it's a totally free full version of Office 365.)

Comment: Other than privacy, Is there a reason to prefer excel over sheets? I find basic UI, functions and macro language of excel very old( exception being Power BI )

Comment: @I'-'I - I don't understand your question. How can basic functions be "old"? - they will always be the same, whether you're talking about `SUM` or `HYPOGEOM.DIST` or even Lookup functions. Macro language: Excel uses VBA (appeared 1993); Google Apps Script calls itself a *lightweight* scripting language and is a simplified form of JavaScript (appeared 1995).  The Excel UI was updated a couple years ago. I prefer a desktop-based app so I can more easily work offline, but I also disagree with you about privacy - I'd consider Google's servers more secure than most. Excel wins by being more common.

Comment: True,But outside of excel, nobody uses vba, while js is still in use almost everywhere in one form or other. vb development has stopped 10 years ago...vba continued much longer,but still... About Functions, I very much prefer gSheets newer functions-ARRAYFORMULA(overflowing into other cells instead  of CSE),REGEX(instead of MID,LEFT), FILTER(),SPLIT(),QUERY()..  While I don't see much of any new excel functions that's of much use(I like TEXTJOIN though, but that's subscription,I think). Agree with offline. Excel is indeed more common.

Comment: @I'-'I Bottom line is it's a matter of personal preference, so no point in debate, but for me, as a developer, there's no point is focusing on a platform that isn't mainstream. [so] has 16K Q&A's about Sheets, and hundreds of thousands about Excel, which is representative of how many users there are worldwide. Many would disagree that "nobody uses VBA outside of Excel", such as advanced Corel or AutoDesk users. Any specialized you can think of (including `TEXTJOIN`) can be recreated in VBA - or with a Google Search. Personally, there's no point in switching since nobody's "paying me" to do so.

Comment: @I'-'I - last thought, I checked out of curiosity, on [so] in the last 2 years, Excel had 10 times as many questions as Sheets, and since the beginning of this year, Excel had 5 times many.  Indeed the gap is closing but still has a long way to go (plus more questions are to be expected of a new platform compared to one that's had knowledge passed from person to person for 3+ decades.)

Comment: Market Dominance is one reason, I think excel is slacking off. A little competition in the spreadsheet world would do a lot of good to the end users. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the easy ones:

- 3) Column headings
- 4) Row headings

The not as as easy as anyone could think:

- In broad terms, 1 and 2 are cells.
- But, on [Excel Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c), 2 is a "header row" and 1 are "banded rows". Other concepts are "calculated column" and "total row".
- Google Sheets hasn't a built-in feature equivalent to Excel Tables.

By the other hand there is another similar feature that is available both in Excel and Google Sheets: "Pivot tables".

On Pivot Tables,

- 2) are column headings
- 1) are data

But there also row headings, summarizing totals, groups, filters among other more concepts.

Sometimes it could be convenient to call 3) and 4) sheet headings but many people just ignores them.

Related

- [Wikipedia: Table (information) - Simple table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(information)#Simple_table)
- [Wikipedia: Spreadsheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet)
- [Wikipedia: Pivot Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table)